# How can I generate the sum of the respective column input without dictionaries or libraries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been provided the following input:

```
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 0
1 2
```

And I have to generate the following output:

```
11 7
```

Is there a way I can implement this function through python without importing any libraries or dictionaries?

Comment: are you going to enter data one by one?

Comment: What have you tried already? Also, is the input provided in a file?

Comment: No mention of whether the input is a string or list or file. Also not mentioned on any thing that is been already tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
no=int(input("How many input?"))
sum_a=0
sum_b=0
for i in range(0,no):
    a,b=input().split()
    sum_a+=int(a)
    sum_b+=int(b)
print(sum_a,sum_b)
```

try this code

```
Output:
How many input?5
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 0
1 2

11 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[1, 2],[2, 1],[3,2],[4,0],[1,2]]
a = 0
b = 0
for i in range(len(list1)):
    a += list1[i][0]
    b += list1[i][1]

print(a,b)
```

to create list use list comprehension

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the data is give as in the question in a file, I would do the following:

```
# Read into a list of lists
data = []
with open("/tmp/data") as f:
    for line in f:
        # strip to remove new-line and split by space
        line_data = line.strip().split(" ")
        # convert to integers
        line_data = [int(x) for x in line_data]
        data.append(line_data)

# Create N lists for N columns in data
# In this case: [0, 0]
sums = [0] * len(data[0]) 

# Iterate all rows and cols and add 
# to the sum
for row in data:
    for col, value in enumerate(row):
        sums[col] += value

print(sums)
```

Output:

```
[11, 7]
```

To read:

- [File handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- [Standard types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) (has string methods)
- [Built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (has enumerate)

Comment: Maybe some feedback on the -1?